# Monotonous function and sets

Tags: functions, set-theory

Hi i have the following question:

> Let $W$ be a set, and $f:P(W)\longrightarrow P(W)$ and "monotonous" function such that for each $A,B\in P(W)$ that satisfy $A\subseteq B:f(A)\subseteq f(B)$
>
> Let $D_0=\emptyset$ and for every $i\in\mathbb{N}:D_{i+1}=f(D_i) $
>
> a. Prove that for every $i\in\mathbb{N}:D_{i}\subseteq f(D_i)$
>
> b. Prove that for every $i\in\mathbb{N}:\bigcup\limits_{i\in\mathbb{N}} D_{i}\subseteq f(\bigcup\limits_{i\in\mathbb{N}}D_i)$

I've proven a with induction, i'm trying to do the same with b, but it seems that it requires to prove that $\bigcup\limits_{i\in\mathbb{N}} D_{i+1}= f(\bigcup\limits_{i\in\mathbb{N}}D_i)$, which i think might be incorrect. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: I can't understand part b.  (Typo?) Because $i $ is not a free variable in the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track.

Try using part (a) and examine what $\bigcup_{n=1}^iD_n$ is for a fixed $i\in\mathbb{N}$.  Notice that from part (a) and the way we defined the $D_i$, the following is true:

$$\emptyset=D_0\subseteq{}f(D_0)=D_1\subseteq{}f(D_1)=D_2\subseteq{}\dots{}$$

Comment: All that i could prove by relying on (a) is: $\bigcup\limits_{i\in\mathbb{N}} D_{i+1}= \bigcup\limits_{i\in\mathbb{N}}f(D_i)$ I get stuck from there